# Google PieChart semi-transparent slice color

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-visualization

It is possible to have a [Google Chart API PieChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) with slices of a semi-transparent color?
I can make a slice completely transparent by passing

```
slices: { 0: { color: 'transparent' }...
```

option to the PieChart, but I can't find the way to make it semi transparent. 
The charts does not recognize the 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' color value ("is not a valid color string"). I also tried to use third column of the data array, passing 'fill-opacity' like this:

```
var data =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Column1', 'Column2', { role:'style' } ],
    ['Val1', 33, 'fill-color: #FF0000; fill-opacity: 0.2'],
    ...
```

That all doesn't have effect on the slice transparency.
The PieChart also doesn't seem to support new 'dataOpacity' configuration option.
I'm testing using the latest Google Chrome version.

Is there a way to have a semi-transparent slice of the google.visualization.PieChart?

Thanks!

Comment: No, transparency is not yet supported for slices in a PieChart.